# JavaFx custom components with Spring

Tags: java, spring, javafx

I'm currently trying to create custom components in JavaFx for my desktop app, and I would like to use Spring DI. 
I have read about how to make extendable components and without Spring I can do it, based on this code https://github.com/matrak/javafx-extend-fxml.

But when I replace the FXMLLoader with a custom [SpringFXMLLoader](https://github.com/seeebiii/PandocGUI/blob/master/src/main/java/de/sebastianhesse/pandocgui/SpringFxmlLoader.java) it can't load the components.

In the main window, there is a button and a editbox, and on click I woul'd like to create a new custom module, with the given name. But it says, that the label in the custom component is null.

What am I doing wrong?

BasicModule.class

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
@DefaultProperty(value = "extension")
public class BasicModule extends BorderPane {
    public Label label;
    public AnchorPane extension;     
    public BasicModule() {
        super();
    }
    public ObservableList<Node> getExtension() {
        return extension.getChildren();
    }
}
```

BasicModule.fxml

```
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity"
     prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
     fx:controller="com.akos.fxmlTest.BasicModule">
  <top>
    <Label fx:id="label" text="Label Basic" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER"/>
  </top>
  <center>
    <AnchorPane fx:id="extension" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER"/>
  </center>
</fx:root>
```

CustomModule.class

```
public class CustomModule extends BasicModule {
@FXML
  public Label customModuleLabel;    

  public void setText(String text) {
    customModuleLabel.setText(text);
  }
}
```

CustomModule.fxml

```
<fx:root type="com.akos.fxmlTest.BasicModule" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
     fx:controller="com.akos.fxmlTest.CustomModule">
<Label fx:id="customModuleLabel" text="asdasdasdasd"/>
</fx:root>
```

Main.class

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfiguration.class);

    context.getBeanFactory().registerResolvableDependency(Stage.class, primaryStage);

    SpringFxmlLoader loader = context.getBean(SpringFxmlLoader.class);
    Parent parent = (Parent) loader.load("/fxml/main.fxml");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(parent, 1000, 600));
    primaryStage.setTitle("test");
    primaryStage.show();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

main.fxml

```
<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.akos.fxmlTest.Controller">
<center>
  <VBox fx:id="itemList" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
     <BorderPane.margin>
        <Insets left="50.0" right="50.0" />
     </BorderPane.margin>
  </VBox>
</center>
 <left>
  <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
     <children>
        <Button fx:id="addButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addNewModule" text="Button" />
        <TextField fx:id="moduleNameEdit" />
     </children>
  </VBox>
 </left>
</BorderPane>
```

Controller.class

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
public class Controller {

public VBox itemList;
public Button addButton;
public TextField moduleNameEdit;

public void addNewModule(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    CustomModule customModule = new CustomModule();
    itemList.getChildren().add(customModule);
    customModule.setText(moduleNameEdit.getText());
}
}
```

AppConfiguration.class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.akos.fxmlTest")
public class AppConfiguration {}
```

Sorry for the wall of text.

Comment: I don't see where you ever load `CustomModule.fxml` (or `BasicModule.fxml`: not really even sure if you intend to load both)

Comment: How should I load it? I've tried to access the SpringFxmlLoader, with autowired context in the BasicModule constructor, and load it with that, but it gave me an error.

Comment: I don't know how you implemented your `SpringFxmlLoader`, but you need to load the FXML. Essentially you are using [this pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components), so you need that code to be executed somehow.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it, for the custom components, they are their own controllers, so you don't want to set the controller factory to use the application context (you already have a controller, you don't want spring to create one in this case). So just use an `FXMLLoader` and call `setController()` and `setRoot()`.

Comment: Ok. I've changed the code to what you suggested, and it works. Thanks for  the help. I just have one final question. Why can't I define the controller in the fxml file? If I use the fx:controller then I get stackoverflow error.

Comment: Because you are already creating the controller elsewhere, using the custom component pattern I linked earlier. If you specify the controller in the fxml file, it is an instruction for the `FXMLLoader` to create one. (So the `FXMLLoader` creates a `CustomModule` instance, via the Spring context, whose constructor loads the fxml, causing the `FXMLLoader` to create a `CustomModule` instance, etc etc.)